# Groovy RESTClient returns inconsistent type on response handler

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I am attempting to write my own response handlers for Groovy's RESTClient (which wraps around HttpBuilder). I want to always print the response body if one is returned. However, I cannot find a consistent way to do it.

Typically a custom response handler would look like this:

```
def client = new RESTClient(url)

client.handler.success = { resp, reader ->
     //do stuff
}

client.handler.failure = { resp, reader ->
     //do stuff
     throw new Exception("HTTP call failed. Status code: ${resp.getStatus()}")
}
```

However, what I noticed is that the variable "reader" can have a different class depending on the response. I've seen the reader be of type `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` or `org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream`. I want it to be a predictable class so I can actually call the methods on this object. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the content type to `ANY` and changing the HttpBuilder content parsers to the text parser fixed the issue. The type of `reader` in the response handler is now always `java.io.InputStreamReader`.

Before:

```
def headerMap = [:]
//populate headers
def response = client.get("headers":headerMap)
```

After:

```
client.parser.'application/xml' = client.parser.'text/plain'
client.parser.'application/xhtml+xml' = client.parser.'text/plain'
client.parser.'application/atom+xml' = client.parser.'text/plain'
client.parser.'application/json' = client.parser.'text/plain'
client.parser.'text/html' = client.parser.'text/plain'
client.parser.'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' = client.parser.'text/plain'
def headerMap = [:]
//populate headers
def response = client.get("headers":headerMap, contentType:groovyx.net.http.ContentType.ANY)
```